# How to call a dart method from Javascript after dart2js

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I got this Dart Script below and I want to access the methods from the class hello_world by JavaScript after I compiled the Dart Script with dart2js.
Does anybody know how this works?!
I already know how to access the functions like foo(...), thats not the problem, but it does not work the same way with classes and methods.
And the tutorials on dartlang.org only explain how to access functions, not methods and classes.
I dont get it...

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

class hello_world {

  String hello = 'Hello World!';

  String getHello() {
    print("getHello!!!!!");
    return hello;
  }

  void ausgabe() {
    print("Hallo Welt");
    //return 0;
  }
}

String foo(int n) {
  print("hallo");

  void foo2() {
    print("hallo2");
  }

  //works
  js.context['foo2'] = foo2;
  return 'Hallo';
}


 void main() {

  int zahl1 = 3;
  int zahl2 = 1234;
  String w = 'test';

  hello_world test = new hello_world();

  //works
  js.context['foo'] = foo;   

}
```

Comment: I think accessing the class is the same as regular function, isn't it? But to use any of its methods you have to instantiate an object first

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099483 for more search for the tag dart-js-interop

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create a Js function bind on a Dart method you can do almost the same thing :

```dart
void main() {
  hello_world test = new hello_world();

  // define a 'getHelloOnTest' Js function
  js.context['getHelloOnTest'] = test.getHello;
}
```

Now on Js side you can use :

```js
getHelloOnTest();
```