# How to check if YouTube video in iframe ended?

Tags: youtube-api, dart

How to check if YouTube video in iframe ended in Dart? I've found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900747/iframe-javascript-check-if-youtube-video-ends), but for JavaScript.

I know, that I could do it with js interop, but I'd like to avoid it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only detect it with the javascript iframe API https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=nl

Comment: And could I use js interop in Dart to achieve this?

Comment: perhaps this is the answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429185/dart-onyoutubeiframeapiready