# When calling dart compiled Javascript from javascript how do I pass in a callback function into dart compiled Javascript?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to convert my project to dart step by step. I have converted a stand alone library to Dart and I'm using the Dart compiled javascript in my project. Thanks for the help in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099483/in-javascript-how-i-use-dart-generated-javascript-file). I'm able to call Dart compiled javascript functions. Now I facing another puzzle. If my Dart function requires a callback, how do I passing a Javascript function into the Dart generated javascript function?

What I am trying to do is register a Dart event handler from Javascript, for example:

in my Dart, I have event bus, dart object can register event handler through:

```dart
bus.on('eventName', callbackFunc);
```

and Dart object fires a event through:

```dart
bus.fire('eventName', data);
```

I expose the bus to Javascript world, through:

```dart
js.context['registerEvent'] = bus.on;
```

In Javascript, I want to call

```dart
registerEvent('someEvent', function() { console.log('JS callback' });
```

to register an event handler, when Dart object fired an event, the JS callback will be invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to just pass it as a parameter to Dart and call it with `param.apply([])`

Comment: param.apply() doesn't work.

Uncaught NoSuchMethodError: Cannot call "apply$0" on "#<JsFunction>" (Object #<JsFunction> has no method 'apply$0')

Comment: Try `param.apply([])`

Answer (score 1):

from your previous question,

```dart
js.context["sayGreeting"] = (message) {
  print("greeting: $message");
};

// pass js function which is already defined above.
someJsObject.callMethod('someOriginalJsFunction', [js.context['sayGreeting']]);
```

Comment: I added more information in my question. Your method won't work because 1. dart didn't know the callback function name. 2. there might not be a function name at all, like the inline function in the question.